# Restrict access to RESTful Resources

Tags: security, rest

In designing a REST API for an application, some services are supposed to be public, while  other services are preferred to be kept private (i.e not publicly accessible). OAuth is used by the service application.

What are the measures to be taken into account ?

Some ideas in mind:

1. Publish private resources under obfuscated URI.
2. Require a special access keys. (to be only known by authorized clients).

Answer (score -1):

The most scalable way is designing the URLs such that it is trivial for an intermediary to know which resources are available for everyone and which for specific users only.

Then a proxy or servlet filter or whatever suits your current needs can do the authorization, blocking all unauthorized requests.
The actual service can now blindly trust and service all requests that do reach it.

Separation of concerns and all that.

Example:

Unauthenticated requests can reach:

```
/myapi/public
```

Request authenticated with username "joe" can also reach:

```
/myapi/personal/joe
```

401 Unauthorised:

```
/myapi/personal/anything_but_joe
```

Make sure /myapi/personal/otheruser and /myapi/personal/nonexistentuser return indistinguishable responses.

Comment: yup, in this case access control would be controlled by OAuth tokens. Only accept a set of known keys. Otherwise I think 404 would satisfy.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  The API should be designed around HATEOAS, which means that your root URI's response (the only URI they should be "bookmarking") simply doesn't provide links to URIs that the given user won't have access to.  If you log in as an admin, you get a totally different set of links returned by the API than someone who logs in as a specific user, and if you are unauthenticated you only ever see public URIs.  IMO those URIs should only describe a resource hierarchy, and not a visibility.  Anyone who has access to that specific resource or feed should have the same URI.

Comment: And by "should" I only mean if you want to create a RESTful service and get the discoverability/robustness benefits of only relying on link relations rather than any URI than the bookmarked "root" URI.  If you don't do HATEOAS, you aren't doing REST - just an HTTP API - which is fine if you don't need those benefits and don't want to do that work :)

Comment: The URL layout I describe is just a server-side implementation detail, without compromising HATEOAS. So while I think you are right, I don't see how it contradicts what I wrote :-) Unless the client is hard-coded to take advantage of the layout without discovery, which is beside my point.

Answer (score -1):

Any resources which need to be protected and constrained to a particular segment of your audience need to have the appropriate access controls in place (basically what you're talking about in point 2). As a guide, refer to APIs from successful services such as Twitter and you'll always find a token involved.

Obfuscation is never acceptable - this is simply [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is fundamentally flawed. Have a good read through part of the OWASP Top 10, [failure to restrict URL access](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A8). The same rules apply to any resources whether they be RESTful or otherwise.

Comment: Access control should be first measure sure, in depth security would be a hard to guess URL.

Comment: Barely worth it and near pointless in lieu of proper access controls: "Security though obscurity is a weak security control": https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Avoid_security_by_obscurity