# Ways to limit / restrict a public API

Tags: security, rest

I have a website through which the user can send emails. The user does not need to register.

To send an email, the following request is sent (per ajax, body contains email adress and message)

```
POST /email/
```

How can I prevent the abuse of the api?

I had the following ideas:

- Each IP may send only a certain number of requests
- Each address may only get a certain number of e-mails

What else can I do?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848535/restrict-access-to-restful-resources

Comment: Sounds like an open relay. Happy spamming!